# Show widget only on specific url

Tags: javascript, html, vk

I have a script in the footer of a site. I want the widget to be shown if url contains 'mystring', and if not, then not to be shown

```
<script>
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("mystring") > -1) {
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?169"></script>
        <!-- VK Widget -->
        <div id="vk_community_messages"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        if($(window).width()>800) { 
        VK.Widgets.CommunityMessages("vk_community_messages", 203651941, {expandTimeout: "20000",tooltipButtonText: "Any Question?"});
        }
        if($(window).width()<=800) {
        VK.Widgets.CommunityMessages("vk_community_messages", 203651941, {tooltipButtonText: "Any Question?"});
        }}
</script>
```

This code produces the following errors:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier (string 3)
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}' (string 12)

Comment: _“This code does not give the desired result.”_ - of course it doesn’t, it should give you _syntax errors_ instead. `<script …>` is not valid JavaScript code, but you put it in a place where JavaScript is expected. Why are you trying to do this in client-side JavaScript in the first place, why not in PHP?

Comment: You've got script tags inside script tags, that isn't going to work. Did you check your console for errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got `<script>` tags and other HTML inside the outer `<script>` tags, that simply isn't allowed and isn't ever going to work. This is a fairly basic thing you *should* have learned when first learning about HTML and JavaScript.

This will make more sense (I can't test it easily so no guarantees it will work exactly, but it certainly won't have any fundamental design flaws or syntax errors, so it should point you down the right road):

```
<div id="vk_community_messages"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?169"></script>
<script>
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("mystring") > -1) {
        if($(window).width()>800) { 
          VK.Widgets.CommunityMessages("vk_community_messages", 203651941, {expandTimeout: "20000",tooltipButtonText: "Any Question?"});
        }

        if($(window).width()<=800) {
          VK.Widgets.CommunityMessages("vk_community_messages", 203651941, {tooltipButtonText: "Any Question?"});
        }
    }
</script>
```